# how to completely destroy a function on component closed?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, antd, cropperjs

I have a vue app form which has an image uploader in it. It has child component where carry the function to crop the image after upload the image from ant-design upload. it's working correctly for upload and crop process. The problem is where it's only work when user firstime upload the image. But in second time upload the image, the crop canvas still using the first image that need to crop. So i destroy the function on it's close or saved by using `this.cropper.destroy()` it's somehow work a little but still have the bug where second time upload will using first image, third time upload will using second image, fourth time upload will using third image and so on. it'll have no user friendly if this bug still there.
Here i'm show my child component code where i want it to be completely destroy on component destroy.

```
<template>
<div>
    <a-row :gutter="16">
        <a-col :span="12">
            <img ref="image" :src="initialImage">
        </a-col>
        <a-col :span="12" align="center">
            <p><strong>Preview</strong></p>
            <img :src="updatedImage" class="preview-image">
        </a-col>
    </a-row>
    <br />
    <a-row :gutter="16">
        <a-button type="primary" style="float: right;" @click="crop">Crop</a-button>
        <a-button style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;" @click="cancel">Cancel</a-button>
    </a-row>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';

export default {
  name: 'PostCropper',
  props: {
    uploadedImage: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cropper: {},
      updatedImage: {},
      image: {},
      initialImage: this.uploadedImage,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    crop() {
      this.$emit('update-image', this.updatedImage);
      this.cropper.destroy();
    },
    cancel() {
      this.$emit('cancel-upload');
      this.cropper.destroy();
    },
    cropImage() {
      this.image = this.$refs.image;
      this.cropper = new Cropper(this.image, {
        zoomable: false,
        scalable: false,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        crop: () => {
          const canvas = this.cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
          this.updatedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        },
      });
    },
  },
  watch: {
    uploadedImage() {
      this.initialImage = this.uploadedImage;
      this.cropImage();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.cropImage();
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
  .preview-image {
    border-radius:100px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
  }
</style>
```

What is actually i need to do for this `this.cropper` completely destroy on page close? Or anything that I can do to overcome this problem?

Comment: You should be using the beforeDestroy hook (see : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram for more information), and use it as : `beforeDestroy: { this.cropper.destroy(); }`

Comment: i have tried this beforeDestroy but the result is still the same @Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of destroy the cropper, i just destroyed whole  child component with v-if so when click the button it will remounted the components

Answer (score 0):

```
  watch: {
    uploadedImage() {
      this.initialImage = this.uploadedImage;
      this.cropper.destroy(); //==> use destroy function here
      this.cropImage();
    },
  },
```

Comment: i have tried this way. but still the same  bug occur

Comment: but this way should be the proper way than i destroy on crop and cancel function. but  it's still the same bug occur.